# My UWP Application Title Bar isn't changing its foreground color in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm working on a cross platform app with Xamarin.Forms and on the UWP side, I added this code in MainPage.xaml.cs to change the app title bar to match the navigation bar I'm using:

```
        var titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
        titleBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.LightSlateGray;
        titleBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.White;
        titleBar.InactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.LightSlateGray;
        titleBar.InactiveForegroundColor = Colors.White;
        titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.LightSlateGray;
        titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.White;
        titleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.LightSlateGray;
        titleBar.ButtonInactiveForegroundColor = Colors.White;
```

However, the foreground color is black when the app is active:

[image]

When the app is inactive, it actually looks correct:

[image]

I've actually noticed that the text shows up as white for a fraction of a second before switching to black. Should I be running this code later, or somewhere else? I've tried before and after LoadApplication. Am I missing something, or is there a better way to handle this in Xamarin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems there may be a bug with setting the foreground color (when active) to exactly white. Perhaps something Xamarin is doing cancels it out. I found that picking a color that is *close* to white works just fine, such as this:

```
var titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
titleBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.LightSlateGray;
titleBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.Snow;
titleBar.InactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.LightSlateGray;
titleBar.InactiveForegroundColor = Colors.White;
titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.LightSlateGray;
titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.Snow;
titleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.LightSlateGray;
titleBar.ButtonInactiveForegroundColor = Colors.White;
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with UWP without using Xamarin Forms. I used `Color.FromArgb(255, 254, 254, 254)` which is the closest achromatic color you can get to White. The hexa value is `#fefefe`.

Comment: A little bit of an off question, how were you able to change the color of the Navigation bar for you app? I am unable to change the color for UWP although the code I have now works fine for Android and iOS.

Comment: How were you able to change the color of the text in the TitleBar?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing in your **UWP** app's OnLaunched method (App.xaml.cs), after the call to Window.Activate.